# When I try to format a date, it renders today's date in my twig template, why is this happening?

Tags: php, wordpress, date, twig, timber

I am using twig templates with wordpress and I am trying to output a date but when I try to format the date it formats correctly but it renders today's date, not the date that I am trying to render.

```
{% for item in program_schedule %}
  {{ item.training_date_current }} // renders correctly 05/Aug/2021
  {{ post.published_at|date("d/M/Y") }} // renders 07/Jul/2021 - should be same as above
{% endfor %}
```

It is very strange, any idea why this is happening and how to fix?
Thank you.

Comment: Verify the variable `post` and it's attribute `published_at` is defined and `published_at` is not null or an empty string. Also did you mean to use the variable `item` instead of `post`?

Comment: @DarkBee even {{ item.training_date_current|date("d/M/Y") }} returns today's date.  The reason I  tried "post.published_at" was because the type is Date. Incase my item.training_date_current was returning a string.

Comment: Then  `training_date_current` is either an empty string or `null`. Doesn't matter if the date is saved as a string - [demo](https://twigfiddle.com/nvtyxb)

Answer (score 0):

Because in a loop you set your singular post as `item` but applying `published_at` at `post` which in Timber may served from global context (basically it is current singular page). You may install [Debug Timber Bar](https://github.com/timber/debug-bar-timber) it will help you to find what in the context or check `{{ dump(_context) }}`. Change your loop to

```
{% for item in program_schedule %}
  {{ item.training_date_current }}
  {{ item.published_at|date("d/M/Y") }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The Debug idea was a good one thank you but the {{ item.published_at|date("d/M/Y") }} didn't resolve the issue. I found the solution, i will write it below as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

In php the date method has 2 arguments from which 1 is optional as mention in [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-description). The string format is required and the second argument being timestamp. If the timestamp is not provided then it takes the current timestamp and gives you today's date (07/Aug/2021). It could be that you expected `post.published_at|date("d/M/Y")` to pass the published_at as second argument which wasn't the case.

You would want to call date method as `date("d/M/Y", $dt)` where $dt is the timestamp. One way of create timestamp is by using `mktime(hour, minute, second, month, day, year)`